# Can I install the Async CTP without breaking anything?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

I'd like to play with the Async CTP. Can I install it on my day-to-day workstation without breaking anything?

I've installed VS2010 SP1. I have ReSharper 5.1.x installed.

Answer (score 0):

The safe answer is "No".

A Community Technology Preview might contain bugs and those bugs might break things.  Even if no one has experienced problems yet, that doesn't necessarily mean there are no problems lurking about - for example what if the bugs are in the uninstall?

The [download page for the CTP Refresh](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983) says this...

> The CTP remains an unsupported and use-at-your-own-risk Technology
>   Preview

On the other hand, the CTP EULA has been modified to allow production use.  That suggests increased confidence in the refresh.  Although that confidence is perhaps more in the code generated using the Async CTP rather than in the Async CTP itself.

Have you considered installing Visual Studio and the CTP on a virtual machine if you don't want to risk affecting your day-to-day system?